# Font parser error

Tags: html, css, angular, webpack

I am developing an angular2 application.I am not able parse the fonts file.
Here I am pasting my webpack.config.js file.

```
    module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.ts$/,
            loaders: "ts-loader!angular2-template-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.css$/,
            loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
        },
        {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            loader: "style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: "html-loader"
        },
        {
            test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf)$/,
            loader: "file-loader"
        }
    ]
}
```

And my style.css file contains font file:

```
    @font-face {
  font-family: 'CentraleSansBook';
  src: url('CentraleSans-Book.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('CentraleSans-Book.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'CentraleSansLight';
  src: url('CentraleSans-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('CentraleSans-Light.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CentraleSansMedium';
  src: url('CentraleSans-Medium.otf') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'CentraleSansXLight';
  src: url('CentraleSans-XLight.otf?#iefix') format('opentype');
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

I am getting error like - **Uncaught Error: Module parse failed, CentraleSans-Book.otf Unexpected character '�'** and **./node_modules/css-loader!./app/styles/styles.css Module not found: Error: Can't resolve CentraleSans-Light.eot'**. please help me to solve this problem.

Tree structure - [image]

Comment: could you add your directory tree relevant excerpt? Where are the fonts located in your project? You mention CentraleSans-Light.eot error but your style.css contain CentraleSansBook in the @font-face, can you complete your question?

Comment: Sorry. I have edited my questions. I have added complete fonts, what I am using.

Comment: can you add the content of the folder who should contain the CentraleSans-Light.eot file ?